# What would be the correct syntax for Collection.toArray()

Tags: java

Collection.[toArray](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)
We use the above method to convert a `List<String>` object to an equivalent `String[]`.

```
List<String> foos = new ArrayList<String>();
// foos.toArray(new String[0]);
// foos.toArray(new String[foos.length]);
```

Which would be the right method to use in order to convert this into an Array.

Comment: foos.toArray(new String[foos.length]); seems better...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one:

```
foos.toArray(new String[foos.size()]);
```

Is the correct one to use. If you give `toArray` an array that is too short to fit the list into, `toArray` will allocate a new array instead of storing the elements in the array you supply. This means that Java will allocate two arrays instead of one and will waste a few clock cycles this way.

Answer (score 2):

If you see the signature of the both functions you will clearly see whats the difference.

```
Object[] toArray();
```

The returned array will be "safe" in that no references to it are maintained by this collection.  (In other words, this method must allocate a new array even if this collection is backed by an array). The caller is thus free to modify the returned array.

This method acts as bridge between array-based and collection-based APIs.

```
<T> T[] toArray(T[] a);
```

`a` the array into which the elements of this collection are to be stored, if it is big enough; otherwise, a new array of the same runtime type is allocated for this purpose.

Comment: Its all depends on what Collection you are working in. In `ArrayList` it better to pass the Length. But in `LinkedList` its not necessary.

Comment: But I would suggest that one should pass the Length to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
String array[] = foos.toArray(new String[foos.size()]);
```

Note that it will also work with new String[0] but the array would need to be reallocated if foos.size() > 0.